# Counting Set Partitions with Constraints

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I'm trying to count set partitions under the following constraints:

- The number of partitions on $n$ elements where the largest cell(s) have exactly $k$ elements
- All cells have at least two elements

Starting [here](http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-password-2009/ams-password33-36-2009/torabiAMS33-36-2009-4.pdf), I'm able to get the number of partitions where the maximum size cell size is exactly $k$ for values of $k \geq \lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Then, for values of $k < \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, I'm trying to add up Stirling numbers:

$$
\sum \limits_{i=\frac {n-k}{2}+1}^\frac {n}{k} {n \brace i} - f(n, i)
$$

where $f(n, i)$ is some function that calculates the number of partitions of $n$ elements into $i$ cells that have at least one cell of size 1.

My thought on the upper limit is that, if you divide up a set into $\frac {n} k$ cells and get rid of anything with size 1, then all cells have to be size $k$ (plus one additional cell for any remainder). Similarly, the low end is where you have one (or two) cells of size $k$ and the rest of them are size $2$.

Where I'm really stuck is getting rid of the partitions that have cells of size $1$. I think I'm headed in the right direction with the approach described above, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B^{\gamma,\mu }_n$ represent the number of partitions where cells have atleast $\gamma$ elements and the size of the largest cell is exactly $\mu$. So the answer to your question would be $B^{2,k}_n$.

Choose an arbitrary element $v$ from the set. Suppose $v$ is in a cell of size $k$ where $\gamma \leq k < \mu$. First we specify $v$'s cell in $n-1 \choose k-1$ ways. Then we partition the remaining elements in $B^{\gamma,\mu}_{n-k}$ ways. Thus we have

$$ \sum_{k=\gamma}^{\mu-1} {n-1 \choose k-1} \, B^{\gamma,\mu}_{n-k}    $$

partitions. Now we have to be careful when $k=\mu$. Since $v$'s cell has $\mu$ elements, we do not need to satisfy the first constraint when we partition the remaining elements. Therefore, they can be partitioned in $B^{\gamma,\gamma}_{n-\mu} + B^{\gamma,\gamma+1}_{n-\mu} + \ ... + \, B^{\gamma,\mu}_{n-\mu}$ ways. So our final recurrence is:

$$ B^{\gamma,\mu}_{n} =  \sum_{k=\gamma}^{\mu-1} {n-1 \choose k-1} \, B^{\gamma,\mu}_{n-k} + \sum_{j=\gamma}^\mu {n-1 \choose \mu-1} \, B^{\gamma,j}_{n-\mu} $$

With base cases

$$ B^{\gamma,\mu}_{n} = \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    0 & : \;\;\; n<\mu \\
    1 & : \;\;\; n = \mu \\
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that  it is quite instructive to  examine this problem using
generating functions and combinatorial classes as presented in
*Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet and Sedgewick.

Using the notation from the  accepted answer we have for partitions of
cell size at  least $\gamma$ and the maximum  element exactly $\mu$
the combinatorial class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\textsc{SET}_{=\gamma}(\mathcal{Z}))
\times \textsc{SET}(\textsc{SET}_{=\gamma+1}(\mathcal{Z}))
\times \textsc{SET}(\textsc{SET}_{=\gamma+2}(\mathcal{Z}))
\\ \times \textsc{SET}(\textsc{SET}_{=\gamma+3}(\mathcal{Z}))
\times \cdots
\times \textsc{SET}(\textsc{SET}_{=\mu-1}(\mathcal{Z}))
\times \textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\textsc{SET}_{=\mu}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This immediately produces the generating function which is
$$G(z) = \left(\exp\left(\frac{z^\mu}{\mu!}\right)-1\right)
\prod_{q=\gamma}^{\mu-1} \exp\left(\frac{z^q}{q!}\right).$$

This is (here we recognize the class
$\textsc{SET}(
\textsc{SET}_{\gamma\le\cdot\le\mu-1}(\mathcal{Z}))$)

$$G(z) = \left(\exp\left(\frac{z^\mu}{\mu!}\right)-1\right)
\exp\left(\sum_{q=\gamma}^{\mu-1} \frac{z^q}{q!}\right).$$

We can extract an **closed** formula from this, getting
$$n! [z^n] G(z)     
= n! \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/\mu \rfloor}
\frac{1}{(\mu!)^k k!}
[z^{n-k\mu}]
\exp\left(\sum_{q=\gamma}^{\mu-1} \frac{z^q}{q!}\right).$$

Now let $\lambda\vdash_\gamma^{\mu-1} (n-k\mu)$ be a partition
of $n-k\mu$ with parts at least $\gamma$ and at most $\mu-1$
and let the multiplicities of $\lambda$ be denoted by
$1^{f_1} 2^{f_2} 3^{f_3} \ldots$ to obtain

$$n! \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/\mu \rfloor}
\frac{1}{(\mu!)^k k!}
\sum_{\lambda\vdash_\gamma^{\mu-1} (n-k\mu)}
\prod_{q=\gamma}^{\mu-1} \frac{1}{(q!)^{f_q} (f_q)!}.$$

Observe that this  formula produces the same values  as the recurrence
from the accepted answer, as can be verified using the following Maple
code:

```
with(combinat);

B :=
proc(g, m, n)
    option remember;

    if n < m then return 0 fi;
    if n = m then return 1 fi;

    add(binomial(n-1,k-1)*B(g, m, n-k), k=g..m-1)
    + add(binomial(n-1, m-1)*B(g, j, n-m), j=g..m);
end;

G :=
proc(g, m, n)
    option remember;
    local gf;

    gf := (exp(z^m/m!)-1)
    *exp(add(z^q/q!, q=g..m-1));

    n!*coeftayl(gf, z=0, n);
end;

Q :=
proc(g, m, n)
    option remember;
    local p, k, res, interm, f;

    res := 0;

    for k to floor(n/m) do
        interm := 0;

        p := firstpart(n-m*k);
        while type(p, list) do
            if min(p) >= g and max(p) <= m-1 then
                f := convert(p, 'multiset');
                interm := interm +
                1/mul((ff[1]!)^ff[2]*ff[2]!, ff in f);
            fi;

            p := nextpart(p);
        od;

        res := res + interm/(m!)^k/k!;
    od;

    n!*res;
end;
```