# Expected Max Pseudotree Size

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, set-partition

I'm working on a problem where I need to calculate the expected maximum pseudotree size in a randomly-generated [pseudoforest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoforest#Directed_pseudoforests) with $n$ nodes.

Expected maximum value is of course:

$$
E(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i\cdot p(i)
$$

Where $i$ is the size of the largest pseudotree in that forest and $p(i)$ is the probability of a tree of size $i$ being the largest tree in the forest.

I'm trying to calculate $p(i)$ based on the following formula, and I'm pretty sure this is where the problem is:

$$
p(i) = \frac{\text{graphs}(i)*\text{partitions}(n, i)}{(n-1)^n}
$$

Where $\text{graphs}(i)$ is the number of pseudotrees with $i$ nodes (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071564/how-many-good-graphs-of-size-n-are-there)) and $\text{partitions}(n,i)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ elements where the largest cell has exactly $i$ values and the smallest has at least 2 (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078391/counting-set-partitions-with-constraints)). Unfortunately for me, this seems to be under counting the numerator for $n>5$. My working theory is that there's a potential division of the elements emerging for larger values of $n$ that is not being counted. Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

I think what may be happening is that I'm forgetting about the different tree configurations for the rest of the partition. I'm investigating that now.

**Edit**

Current attempt at counting the remaining configurations:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}graphs(j)\cdot partitions(n-i,j)
$$

Comment: Did your second edit yield the results you were after?